# Find encoding based on input and output

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

I have a byte representation of a string, no idea what is the encoding, I know that `b'\x04\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x9f\x90\x9f\x00'` represents (fish character). Is it possible to find the encoding based on this information?
I checked  `print(b'\x04\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x9f\x90\x9f\x00')`  prints , so terminal knows its encoding, not me.

Comment: 9 bytes??? What is the *fish char*? You should check which encoding has it (I doubt there are many).

Comment: right 9 bytes, python print doesn't complain that.

Comment: Looks like there's lots of useless `NUL` bytes and an `EOT` byte. The actual character is just 4 bytes towards the end there.

Comment: `print(b'\x9f\x90\x9f\x00')` prints `???`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\xf0\x9f\x90\x9f` is the UTF-8 encoded character U+1F41F FISH.
The rest are useless `NUL` bytes and one `0x04` `EOT` byte, which don't do a lot usually.

Comment: how to decode these bytes? I am getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 1: invalid start byte`

Comment: original bytes to decode are `b'\x03\x91\x0b\x08,\xfa\xbemm\xad3\xa0\x903\x9eO5\xd3\x15yc\x8c6e\xa4\xcf\xd3\xa2\xbcN\xbcZ\x83\xac\xc5\x86O\x9c\xcc\x8d\xa8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x9f\x90\x9f\x00\x11Mined by leiailan\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

Comment: I can find the string needed in python2, but not in python 3

Comment: http://xyproblem.info? You seem to need to decode some very specific binary format, so you should get to know more about how it's specified.

Comment: thanks, I found solution without needing to know the encoding.